# Bloomberg API, pybbg

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm trying to extract bloomberg data using the BDS formula in python and I have downloaded the pybbg library. I want to include several overrides but I get an error. What I'm trying to extract is done following with the excel API addin: =BDS("SUBC NO Equity","PG_REVENUE","PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE=G","FUND_PER=Q"=
For one override, following code works (https://github.com/kyuni22/pybbg):

```
import unittest
import datetime
import pybg

class TestPybbg(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bds(self):
        tester = pybbg.Pybbg()
        data = tester.bds('SUBC NO Equity','PG_REVENUE',overrides={'FUND_PER': 'Q'})
        print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Following Error arises if the Company doesn't have that level detail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bloomberg/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 23, in test_bds_override
    data = tester.bds('AKSO NO Equity','PG_REVENUE',overrides={'PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE':'G','FUND_PER':'Q'})
  File "C:\Users\bloomberg\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\pybbg-0.0.1-py3.6.egg\pybbg\pybbg_k.py", line 295, in bds
    fieldData = securityData.getValue(i).getElement("fieldData").getElement(field)
  File "C:\Users\bloomberg\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\blpapi\element.py", line 347, in getElement
    _ExceptionUtil.raiseOnError(res[0])
  File "C:\Users\bloomberg\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\blpapi\exception.py", line 145, in raiseOnError
    _ExceptionUtil.raiseException(errorCode, description)
  File "C:\Users\bloomberg\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\envs\work\lib\site-packages\blpapi\exception.py", line 137, in raiseException
    raise errorClass(description, errorCode)
blpapi.exception.NotFoundException: Attempt to access unavailable sub-element 'PG_REVENUE' of element 'fieldData'. (0x0006000d)
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Following error arises if the the data is not available:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, if you add the following to the formula you can include several overrides:

```
data = tester.bds('SUBC NO Equity','PG_REVENUE',overrides={'PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE':'G','FUND_PER':'Q'})
```